CropperJS - fixed target image size
I'm making a page for staff to upload a profile photo for their ID cards. The final image must be 500x500px when submitted. I'm trying to use cropperjs to allow the user to select a square of at least 500x500 which is then resized down (not up) to 500x500px. E.g. if a user uploads a 5000x8000px image then the can draw a square over the image which is at least 500px on each side and then upload the cropped image.
Obviously the image is displayed in its entirety and then the square that is drawn is proportionally the minimum size
Is this possible with CropperJS?
